# Make callout to changing subdomain of URL

Tags: callout, url, dynamic

I am using CloudConvert to generate previews of my files. 
CloudConvert is firstly getting call for URL:

URL: `api.cloudconvert.com/process`

And then, on the second call its Url changes to

URL: `smt_instantly_changed.cloudconvert.com/process/another_instantly_changed_path`

i.e.

```
URL: //host123d1qm.cloudconvert.com/process/cqpENkvYlnIja65TUZCH
```

How can add a remote sites to allow me make a HTTP Request?

Comment: simply add `https://host123d1qm.cloudconvert.com/` in Remote site setting.

Comment: however it is changing... not static.. for example 

host123d1qo.cloudconvert.com/process/20Bfr3nTeU6IotNslvmj
host123d1qj.cloudconvert.com/process/mv1eYwdtH4GrjnfcQhLS
host123d1qe.cloudconvert.com/process/S3Zt6DBqUg0R782XysbC",

Comment: then I afraid but you need to add all of them. Not sure if SF support `http://*.cloudconvert.com/` you can try this.

Comment: It does not support I've tried =)

Comment: I think, just last char of subdomain is changing... At least I can add for 28 letter. Even it is completely opposite to my programming prenciples =)

Comment: I told with cloudconvert support and they recommend me to setup a kind of proxy (I mean middleware server) pass requests from salesforce to cloudconvert.

Answer (score 1):

I told with cloudconvert support and they recommend me to setup a kind of proxy (I mean middleware server) to pass requests from salesforce to cloudconvert.

The second viable option is communicate with cloudconvert from client browser (make requests using javascript).